# I am trying to extract data from excel sheet with and without def statement (functions) in python

Tags: python, excel, selenium

I have recently started learning PYTHON and I am facing some difficulty.

I am trying to extract data from excel sheet  with and without def statement . So without def, I am getting valid output but when I extract data using def statement, I am getting "NONE" as output. Please help me to resolve this.

```
book=xlrd.open_workbook("E:\\Email.xlsx")

print(book.nsheets)

SheetName =book.sheet_by_name("gmail")

rows=SheetName.nrows

cols=SheetName.ncols

print(rows)

print(cols)
```

**##### WITHOUT DEFINING ANY FUNCTION ####**

```
table=list()

record=list()

for x in range(rows):

    for y in range(cols):

        record.append(SheetName.cell(x,y).value) 

        table.append(record)

        record=[]

        rows=rows+1

print(table)
```

> O/P:[['Email ID:'], ['AVVC.com'], ['Password'], ['abcdefg']]

**WITH DEF**

```
def getcell(rows,cols):

table=list()

record=list()


for x in range(rows):

    for y in range(cols):

        record.append(SheetName.cell(x,y).value) 

        table.append(record)

        record=[]

        rows=rows+1

        return;

v= getcell(0,1)

print(v)
```

O/P:NONE

Comment: Your function is not returning anything.  Try `return table`.

Comment: Same O/P : None

Answer (score 0):

When you call `return` in a `function` it stops the execution and passes back whatever is after it.

As you had your `return` with nothing after it, it was returning `None` (nothing). What you want to do is return the `table` `list` so that it works in the same way as when there wasn't a `function`. Also, as `return` stops the execution, it needs to be at the very end of your `function`  - after the `for-loops` so that they can complete.

Making your `function`:

```
def getcell(rows,cols):
    table=list()
    record=list()
    for x in range(rows):
       for y in range(cols):
            record.append(SheetName.cell(x,y).value) 
            table.append(record)
            record=[]
            rows=rows+1

    return table
```